# Is there something like onFirendRequestAccepted?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm starting to work with discord API via discord.py module. I've been through docs, but I've not found anything like this.

So, here's the question:

Is there some event trigger like `onFirendRequestAccepted` which runs the function when someone accept your friend request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below is outdated since v2.0 of `discord.py`, which removes the 3 events listed.

### Old answer:

The rewrite branch contains `on_relationship_add`, `on_relationship_remove` and `on_relationship_update`.

http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html?highlight=friend#discord.on_relationship_add

Comment: Thanks for the effort. That's just what I needed!